# UIPanGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail delays UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uipangesturerecognizer

i have a UIPanGestureRecognizer on my rootViewControllers view

that controls only 2 finger swipe ( min and max are set on 2 )

I have a couple of UITableView and UIScrollView on my rootViewControllers view.
But the 2 finger swipe should always have number 1 priority

so i put a requireGestureRecognizerToFail on my UITableView and UIScrollView's panGesture property.

this works perfectly but now when i pan my UITableView and UIScrollView, it doesn't move until i stop swiping.

Is there a solution for this?

i have added a sample project to display what the problem is: https://github.com/avalanched/UIScrollViewTest

Answer (score 1):

You will need to allow the gesture recognizers to simultaneously recognize by setting the delegate on all the gesture recognizers and implementing `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`.

See Apple's [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate).

You also need to remove the requireGestureRecognizerToFail calls, these are what causes the delay.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UIScrollView's built-in pan gesture recognizer must have its scroll view as its delegate.'

Comment: I'd tried overwriting the tableview and setting the delegate to itself, putting both gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer to YES which works, but i still have the same problem.

Comment: The scrollview is likely the one causing the problem, have you tried setting the maximumNumberOfTouches to 1 on the scrollview pan gesture recognizer?

Comment: I have done that 2, check the sample project: https://github.com/avalanched/UIScrollViewTest

Comment: @AndyJacobs I ran your test code, removing the calls to requireGestureRecognizerToFail: fixed the issue now that you have the simultaneous recognition setup.

Comment: I know but i want limit the simultaneous use, 2 finger swipe always has priority

Comment: Then you are gonna have the delay, there aren't any other parameters to prioritize one over the other and failing takes some amount of time.

Comment: The table view starts having performance problems on the recognizer after scrolling, possibly due to multiple cells registering their pan recognizers this way. Is there a way to unhook this relationship between the recognizers?